How to configure RequestLog for multiple webappcontext in jetty12
RequestLogHandler has been removed from jetty12, we should configure Server.setRequestLog for request logging. But with this setup we cannot seperate request logs per different webappcontext and all the requests will be logged to a single file. Any suggestions on how can we achieve this, it would be a great help. Thank you.
Note : we used WebAppContext.insertHandler(RequestLogHandler) in jetty10 and jetty11 to achieve the above setup.
I tried configuring as below. But the RequestLog doesn't belong in a WebAppContext configuration and its creating a new server instance and couldn't log the requests.
This should be done at startup of the Server.
Please look into the below code snippet. Example.xml
<Configure id="Example" class="org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New id="RequestLogWriter" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.RequestLogWriter">
      <Set name="filename">/tmp/example-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</Set>
      <Set name="filenameDateFormat"><Property name="jetty.requestlog.filenameDateFormat" default="yyyy_MM_dd"/></Set>
  </New>

  <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.CustomRequestLog">
      <Arg><Ref refid="RequestLogWriter"/></Arg>
      <Arg>
        <Property name="jetty.customrequestlog.formatString">
          <Default>%{client}a - %u %t \"%r\" %s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"</Default>
        </Property>
      </Arg>
  </New>

  <Call name="setServer">
    <Arg>
      <New id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
          <Set name="RequestLog"><Ref refid="RequestLogImpl"/></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>

Findings :

Using RequestLog, we cannot seperate the requestlogs based on the WebAppContext. There's no webapp specific RequestLog support.

Requirement :

I want to record request logs per webappcontext, If there is any workaround kindly share.


This question is similar to: Porting from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12. Missing RequestLogHandler. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@TorgeRosendahl Updated the post.

Follow up :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79253987/requestlogs-arent-getting-recorded-with-siftingappender
