RequestLogs aren't getting recorded with siftingappender
This is a workaround for my previous question. How to configure RequestLog for multiple webappcontext in jetty12
In jetty12, Since the RequestLog only exists on the Server level we can't seperate them into different targets based on their webappcontext. I tried the below method to achieve this.
Current Problem - "whenever a http request is made, the server checks for MDC.get(contextPath) before entering into the filterchain itself. the contextPath is null and always logs to default file. But i want to record request log events based on contextPath.
Below are the details, can someone please help if am missing something."
1.MDCHandler.java (created a MDCHandler.jar and placed under jetty-base/lib/ext. Add the filter mapping to the webapp.
package com.example.MDCHandler;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MDCHandler implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MDCHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // Initialization logic, if any
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        logger.info("Before setting MDC: contextPath={}, requestId={}", MDC.get("contextPath"), MDC.get("requestId"));
        
        // Set MDC context based on the request path or other relevant information
        String contextPath = httpRequest.getContextPath();
        String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        
        MDC.put("contextPath", contextPath);
        MDC.put("requestId", requestId);

        // Log MDC values to ensure they're being set correctly
        logger.info("After setting MDC: contextPath={}, requestId={}", MDC.get("contextPath"), MDC.get("requestId"));

        // Ensure MDC context is propagated to worker threads
        Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        
        // For asynchronous tasks or worker threads, propagate MDC context
        Runnable task = () -> {
            if (contextMap != null) {
                MDC.setContextMap(contextMap);  // Propagate MDC context to the new thread
            }
            // Do some work in the worker thread, and logging will use the MDC context
            logger.info("This log comes from the worker thread with MDC context.");
        };

        // Example of submitting the task to a thread pool or new thread
        new Thread(task).start();  // Or submit it to a thread pool if applicable

        try {
            // Continue filter chain processing
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            // Clear MDC context after the request is processed
            MDC.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Cleanup, if any
    }
}

2.jetty-requestlog.xml (Used slf4j requestLogWriter instead of RequestLogWriter)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10_0.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <Set name="RequestLog">
    <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.CustomRequestLog">
      <!-- Writer -->
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Slf4jRequestLogWriter">
            <Set name="loggerName">jetty.requestlog</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>

      <!-- Format String -->
      <Arg>
        <Property name="jetty.requestlog.formatString" deprecated="jetty.customrequestlog.formatString">
          <Default>
            <Get class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.CustomRequestLog" name="EXTENDED_NCSA_FORMAT"/>
          </Default>
        </Property>
      </Arg>
    </New>
  </Set>

</Configure>

3.logback.xml (setup the logger and siftingappender based on the contextPath).
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator">
            <key>contextPath</key>
            <defaultValue>/default</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${contextPath}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>./logs${contextPath}.request.log</file> 
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>[%X{contextPath:-not-set}] [%X{requestId}] %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>
    <logger name="jetty.requestlog" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
    </logger>

</configuration>

logFile created : ./logs/default.request.log. Contents/requestlog events are as follows. We can see the contextPath is not set by MDCHandler yet.
[not-set] [] [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] - - [05/Dec/2024:17:59:50 +0000] "GET /example/alive HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.29.0"
[not-set] [] [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] - - [05/Dec/2024:18:00:02 +0000] "GET /example/alive HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.29.0"

